# JQuery remote validator always returns false

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

I have a page with ZipCode field, which I need to validate on server. 
When the page is loaded ZipCode must be already prefilled from some external source.

I added a jquery remote validator in order to validate this field:
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("#Buyer_ZipCode").rules("add", {
        remote: { url: zipcodeValidationUrl, async: false },
        messages:
           {
               remote: "Cannot determine location for given zip code."
           }
    });

    var zipcode = $("#Buyer_ZipCode");
    if (zipcode.val().length > 0) {
        zipcode.trigger('blur');
    };

});
```

In order to do the actions at once after the page load I added a blur trigger. My Blur handler:

```
$("#Buyer_ZipCode").bind('blur', function (e) {       

    //some actions

    element = $(e.target);        
    if (!element.valid()) {
        console.log(element.val());
        // Invalidate lookup target control.
        targetCity.get(0).value = "";
        targetState.get(0).value = "";
        return;
    };

 // yet some actions

});
```

Everything works normally, except the situation when the page is loaded and we already have a value for ZipCode field. In this case valid() method always returns false, nevertheless remote validion is not async and the server *really* returns true. By the way, this is my validation controller

```
 public JsonResult IsZipCodeValid([NestedFieldModelBinder]string Buyer_ZipCode)
    {
        if (Utils.GetZipcode(Buyer_ZipCode) != null)
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json("Cannot determine location for given zip code.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Small addition. When entered zipcode doesn't pass server validation I see the error message, but when it pass - only jquery.valid(0 method returns false, but without any messages

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it much simpler and cleaner to use the [RemoteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) .

In your viewmodel add a Remote[] attribute to your Buyer_ZipCode property

```
[Remote("ValidateZipCode", HttpMethod="Post", ErrorMessage = "Cannot determine location for given zip code.")]
public string Buyer_ZipCode{ get; set; }
```

And your action for validation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateZipCode(string Buyer_ZipCode)
{
    // do your validation
    return Json(true);
}
```

Regards

Comment: thank you for your answer. The reason why I choosed jquery validation of instead Remote attribute is that jquery remote can be made in synchronous request.